# how to fetch last value for column in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

How can I fetch last value of column in dataframe.

```
close_value = from_csv['close_price'].tail(1)
```

Here is from_csv is my dataframe
This gives me the needed output but in different format(given below)

```
 Name: close_price, dtype: float64
    1    0.985
```

I just want to store .985 in variable

Comment: try close_value = from_csv['close_price'].tail(1)[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
from_csv.close_price.iloc[-1]
```

`iloc` selects by position, `-1` means last position.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the most straightforward method, but for me the following seems to do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df['a'].values[-1]
```